# Collect a Stream to a LinkedList

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When streaming through `List`, how can I collect the output to a linked list?

I have tried the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
    firstList.add("pavan");
    firstList.add("kumar");
    LinkedList<String> filtered= new LinkedList<>();
    filtered = (LinkedList<String>) firstList.stream().filter(t->firstList.contains("p")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(filtered);        
}
```

But this is giving  **java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList.**

Comment: Is there a special reason _why_ you need a `LinkedList` and cannot code against the `List` interface?

Comment: I wanted to use  Deque interface methods implemented by LinkedList

Comment: Okay, it would then still be best to code against the interface and declare the variable as `Deque<String>`.

Comment: How is that @MickMnemonic

Comment: Doing so would make it simpler to later on switch to another implementation (e.g. `ArrayDeque`, `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`, `LinkedBlockingDeque`). More reasons why it's a good idea, in general, in this post: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: I am asking about how to name variables like Deque<String> and still code against Interface.Can you please explain

Comment: Use `Deque<String> filtered=firstList.stream() .filter(t -> t.contains("p")) .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));` Note that I replaced `LinkedList` with `ArrayDeque`, as there is really no use case for `LinkedList`, even if you need a `Deque`. Further, I replaced your filter expression with something, that is more likely matching your intention.

Answer (score 21):

`collect(Collectors.toList())` returns a `List`. You can't assume which `List` implementation it will return.

Use `Collectors.toCollection()`, to specify the actual `Collection` (or `List` in your case) implementation you wish to collect the data into :

```
LinkedList<String> filtered =
    firstList.stream()
             .filter(t->firstList.contains("p"))
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use constructor

```
 filtered = new LinkedList<String>(firstList.stream().filter(t->firstList.contains("p")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Linked list constructor takes `Collection` as argument so any return from `asList()` will be compatible

Comment: Use of `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))` is more efficient. if you use copy-constructor, 2 lists would be created.